# String Manipulation using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Using C# we can do string check like if string.contains() method, e.g.:

```
string test = "Microsoft";
if (test.Contains("i"))
    test = test.Replace("i","a");
```

This is fine. But what if I want to replace a string which contains "  symbol to be replaced.

I want to achieve this:

```
"<html><head>
```

I want to remove the `"` symbol present in check so that the result would be:

```
<html><head>
```

Comment: You don't need check contains first, replace doesn't throw exception, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The " character can also be replaced, just like any other:

```
test = test.Replace("\"","");
```

Also, note that you don't have to test if the character exists : your **test.Contains("i")** could be removed since the **.Replace()** method won't do anything (no replace, no error thrown) if the character doesn't exist inside the string.

Comment: I prefer this answer as it removes the superfluous `.Contains()`

Answer (score 1):

To include a quote symbol in a string, you need to escape it, using a backslash.  In your example, you want to use something lik this:

```
if (test.Contains("\""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string SymbolString = "Micro\"so\"ft";
```

The string above use scape char \ to insert " between the characters

```
string Result = SymbolString.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

With the following replace I replace the character "" for empty.

This is what you try to achieve?

Comment: You're welcome :) However it will not work. Either `String.Replace(String,String)` or `String.Replace(Char,Char)` but not a mix, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to include a `'"'` character in a string literal.  All the answers so far have used the c-style way:

```
var quotation = "Parting is such sweet sorrow";
var howSweetIsIt = quotation + " that I shall say \"good-night\" till it be morrow.";
```

In some contexts (especially for users experienced with Visual Basic), the verbatim string literal may be easier to read.  A verbatim string literal begins with an @ sign, and the only character that requires escaping is the quotation mark -- all other characters are included verbatim (hence the name).  Significantly, the method of escaping the quotation mark is different: rather than preceding it with a backslash, it must be doubled:

```
var howSweetIsIt = quotation + " that I shall say ""good-night"" till it be morrow.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (check.Contains("\"")
    output = check.Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: You don't need check contains first, replace doesn't throw exception, it just does nothing.

Comment: I know. I just wrote example similar as one in question

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str.Contains("\""))
{
    str = str.Replace("\"", "");
}
```

Comment: You don't need check contains first, replace doesn't throw exception, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = check.Replace("\"", "");
```

Just remember to use `"\""` for the quote sign as the backslash is an [escape character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx).